# What is the meaning of EMS and BMS in an ANOVA?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

For an ANOVA, what is the meaning of the Error Mean Squares (EMS, or similarly TMS) and also the Between Mean Squares (BMS)? I know how they are calculated, but what meaning do they actually hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working with a balanced one-way ANOVA design, with model
$$ Y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + e_{ij},$$
where $\sum \alpha_i = 0$ and $e_{ij} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0, \sigma^2),$
and $i = 1, \dots, g$ groups and $j = 1, \dots, n$ replications per group.

Then MSE is an unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$ regardless whether the
null hypothesis $H_0: \alpha_1 = \cdots \alpha_g$ is true. It is a generalization
of the 'pooled' estimate of $\sigma^2$ in a pooled 2-sample t test.

By contrast, BSE is an estimate of $\sigma^2$ that is unbiased if $H_0$
is true, and has positive bias if $H_0$ is false. (The bias is a funcation
of $\sum \alpha_i^2.$)

Thus the variance ratio statistic $F = BMS/EMS$ tends to be 'near' 1 when
$H_0$ is true and larger than 1 when $H_0$ is false.

The 'sufficient statistics' for such an ANOVA (in addition to the known
sample sizes), are the $g$ sample means $\bar Y_{i \cdot}$ and the $g$ sample variances $S_i^2.$ BMS depends on the data only via these means, and EMS depends on the data only through the variances. So BMS and EMS are independent
estimates of $\sigma^2$ as required by the derivation of Snedecor's F-distribution.

The DF's in an ANOVA table can be interpreted as dimensions of sub-spaces in
the $gn$-dimensional space of the data $Y_{ij}.$ One dimension is 'used'
to estimate $\mu$ by $\bar Y_{\cdot \cdot} = \frac{1}{gn} \sum_i \sum_j Y_{ij}.$
The $g-1$-dimensional sub-space of BMS and the $g(n-1)$-dimensional sub-space of EMS are orthogonal to each other and to the space of the grand mean $\bar Y_{\cdot \cdot}$.